# How to remove duplicate string in big string data?

Tags: java, blackberry

e.g. i am getting data like "vivartvivartpandey"
i want output like "vivartpandey"
Only one thing is fixed that data will come either like string1+string1+string2
or like string1+string2 (no duplicate)
but string1 and string2 both are variable.

So How to identify string1 and remove duplicate string1?

Comment: `'vivartvivartpandey' -replace '(.+)\1','$1'` seems to work at least for your example in PowerShell. No idea about Java (should work too) and no idea whether it would work correctly in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to create a simple solution.

```
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= text.length() / 2; i++) {
        String string1 = text.substring(0, i);
        String string2 = text.substring(i, 2 * i);
        if (string1.equals(string2)) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("without duplicate: " + text.substring(index));
```

Answer (score 2):

we need more constraints to be able to achieve this. For example, if you get "ssssabcd", there is no way to find out if the string1 is "ssss" or "ss" (i.e if repetition occured)

Comment: sorry i didn't clarify this situation. but this case will not come. Characters can repeat but not like that.e.g. "sssiefgsssiefabcd"

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression like this:

```
String s = "vivaryvivartypadney";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\g(-1)(.*)").matcher(s);

if (m.find())
    String prefix = m.group(1), suffix = m.group(2);
```

The first parenthesis in the regexp define a group, and the \g(-1) is a relative reference to the prior matching group.  Now, if your string were something like "vivavivavivavivaChile", you'd get a match, but only because of the 'first' duplication, not the longer second one (as other answer mentions).  I'll leave it to you to put this in a loop to get the longest such match if you want that.